# Grails render template or JSON?

Tags: json, grails

I have a controller that uploads and processes a file. Afterwards, I wish to render the processing result in a modal div. I wanted to know what the best way is to get the results from the controller to the modal div on the gsp. I thought about a template but I didn't know how to specify what the target div for the template should be because this template wouldn't be rendered by a button click where a target for template render is set as an attribute, it would be done on a timed basis (i.e. when the file is done uploading). The other way is to send JSON back from the controller but I don't know how to intercept this JSON at the right time because I still don't quite understand the timings of the information flow between the GSP and the Controller. I know how to send the JSON but how to alert the GSP that "hey, some JSON is now ready for your modal that's about to go up." Here is some pseoducode of basically what I am trying to get done.

Controller:

```
 upload() {
    // process file and store results in three integers
    // int1 = result1
    // int2 = result2
    // int3 = result3
    // send the three numbers to the gsp
    }
```

Now what is the best way to get these three numbers to the GSP so that they are displayed on a modal dialog which is about to go up like this:

```
<div id="fileUploadResultsModal">
Results:
${int1}, ${int2}, ${int3}
</div>
```

Here is the JS associated with my ajax upload function:

```
$("#chseFile").upload("${createLink(controller: 'customer', action: 'upload',)}",
                                            {dataTypegrp: parseInt(getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('dataTypegrp'))),
                                             fileTypegrp: parseInt(getCheckedValue(document.getElementsByName('fileTypegrp')))}, 
                                            function(success) {
                                                    $("#cancel1").trigger("click");
                                                    setTimeout(function(){ 
                                                        $("#summary").trigger("click");
                                                    }, 250);
                                                    displaySuccess(data);
                                            }, 
                                            function(prog, value) {
                                                console.log(value);
                                                $("#prog").val(value);
                                                if (value == 100) {
                                                    $("#prog").hide();
                                                    $("#progressbar").html("Uploading and processing. Please wait...");
                                                }
});
```

but right now JS complains that 'data' is not defined. 'data' is meant to be the JSON coming back from the controller.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can render them as JSON:

```
render( [ int1:111, int2:222, int3:333 ] as JSON )
```

or as a HTML-string

```
render "<div id=\"fileUploadResultsModal\">Results:${int1}, ${int2}, ${int3}</div>"
```

or use a template

```
render template:'/yourController/templateName', model:[ int1:111, int2:222, int3:333 ]
```

or a `TagLib`

```
render g.yourResultTag( int1:111, int2:222, int3:333 )
```

For this tiny bit of information, the performance is not of concern. It's rather a matter of taste, or what is more appropriate for your client.

If the later is JSON-biased, use JSON-rendering. If it has a mix of JSON and HTML, use others.

Comment: How would I control which already existing 'div' I render into if I went the JSON route as in your first example?

Comment: post your JS code. it should be really simple everywhere

Comment: Central to my problem is the fact that I do not fully understand the ajax sequence. I have an ajax call to upload a file and a success function associated with that but I don't know how to tell the success function to get the JSON data rendered back from the controller. Like for example in formRemote you can have an attribute OnSuccess="doResult(data)". However, since this is my own JS ajax call, I don't understand how to get to the 'data' variable rendered by the controller. I updated the original post with JS code.

Comment: looks like the `data` var is either the `success` argument of `function(success) {..}` or it's field. Debug the function call in Firebug and see. what plugin are you using?

Comment: so, `success` argument must be your text to show. you should call `displaySuccess( success )`.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. Now I understand. That was the key part I wasn't understanding. Once you told me, I got it to work.

Answer (score 0):

inside controller at the enf of controller action you can use

```
render [data:['name':'firstname','surname':'secondName'] as JSON]
```

this will render the data to GSP